# woocommerce custom filter when click on a subcategory

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

does it do the following:
Check this: http://www.nalyfashion.com/images/face-shape_z383i17k.jpg
suppose we have that on top of page and every face shape is click-able and when you click it produces a selection of earrings earrings are filtered based on length and/or width
for example, round face shape: `width = length < 0.5 cm`
for oblong face shapes: `length > 3 cm`
etc
possible?
it's basically a set of filters:

```
category = jewlery
subcategory = earrings
length = etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Product Attributes](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/#section-3) would be perfect for this. Alternatively, you could create [product tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/#section-2) and tag them based on various length/widths.

There are other options, but these are the most "out of the box."